# Adjust packing coordinates in a bin if an additional bin is added

Tags: python, coordinates, matplotlib-3d, bin-packing

I have been using Py3dbp to pack some items in a container and I got it to work with a Gui so when I select an item in a list in the Gui, the item is highlighted in the container as such:

[image: Container with item selected on Gui, No walking room]

Now I need to add a walking room, or an empty space in the first container so that a person can walk into the container like this:

[image: Container with walking room, broken 1]

[image: Container with walking room, broken 2]

What I need to happen is when I turn the walking room to True, the red box is there and the packer or bin class checks for that dimension, and packs the items around the walking room in the same order and priority that the packer class already has set up.  I have tried a lot of different ways for the item loading to look at the dimensions but nothing seems to work as I have floating items or items overlapping the walking room.

Here is the Packer class:

```
class Packer:

    def __init__(self):
        ''' '''
        self.bins = []
        self.items = []
        self.unfit_items = []
        self.total_items = 0
        self.binding = []
        # self.apex = []


    def addBin(self, bin):
        ''' '''
        return self.bins.append(bin)


    def addItem(self, item):
        ''' '''
        self.total_items = len(self.items) + 1

        return self.items.append(item)


    def pack2Bin(self, bin, item,fix_point,check_stable,support_surface_ratio):
        ''' pack item to bin '''
        fitted = False
        bin.fix_point = fix_point
        bin.check_stable = check_stable
        bin.support_surface_ratio = support_surface_ratio

        # first put item on (0,0,0) , if corner exist ,first add corner in box. 
        if bin.corner != 0 and not bin.items:
            corner_lst = bin.addCorner()
            for i in range(len(corner_lst)) :
                bin.putCorner(i,corner_lst[i])

        elif not bin.items:
            response = bin.putItem(item, item.position)

            if not response:
                bin.unfitted_items.append(item)
            return

        for axis in range(0, 3):
            items_in_bin = bin.items
            for ib in items_in_bin:
                pivot = [0, 0, 0]
                w, h, d = ib.getDimension()
                if axis == Axis.WIDTH:
                    pivot = [ib.position[0] + w,ib.position[1],ib.position[2]]
                elif axis == Axis.HEIGHT:
                    pivot = [ib.position[0],ib.position[1] + h,ib.position[2]]
                elif axis == Axis.DEPTH:
                    pivot = [ib.position[0],ib.position[1],ib.position[2] + d]
                    
                if bin.putItem(item, pivot, axis):
                    fitted = True
                    break
            if fitted:
                break
        if not fitted:
            bin.unfitted_items.append(item)
#########
    #     walking_room_x = bin.width / 4
    #     walking_room_y = bin.height / 2
    #     walking_room_z = bin.depth
    #         # Iterate over the walking room dimensions
    #     for x in range(int(walking_room_x), int(walking_room_x) + 24):
    #         for y in range(int(walking_room_y), int(walking_room_y) + 24):
    #             for z in range(int(walking_room_z)):
    #             # Check if the item fits in the walking room and does not intersect with other items
    #                 item.position = [x, y, z]
    #                 if self.isItemFittingInWalkingRoom(item, bin.items):
    #                 # If the item fits, pack it based on the order set in the Packer class
    #                     self.packItemInOrder(bin, item, fix_point, check_stable, support_surface_ratio)
    #                     return


    # def isItemFittingInWalkingRoom(self, item, items_in_bin):
    # # Check if the item fits within the bin excluding the walking room area
    #     item_width, item_height, item_depth = item.getDimension()

    #     for existing_item in items_in_bin:
    #         # Check for intersection with existing items
    #         if intersect(existing_item, item):
    #             return False

    #     # Access bin dimensions from the first bin in the list (you may need to adapt this based on your logic)
    #     if not self.bins:
    #         return False

    #     bin_width = self.bins[0].width
    #     bin_height = self.bins[0].height

    #     # Check if the item fits in the bin excluding the walking room
    #     if (
    #         0 <= item.position[0] < bin_width and
    #         0 <= item.position[1] < bin_height and
    #         0 <= item.position[2] < item_depth and
    #         item.position[0] + item_width <= bin_width - int(bin_width / 4) and
    #         item.position[1] + item_height <= bin_height - int(bin_height / 2) and
    #         item.position[2] + item_depth <= bin_depth
    #     ):
    #         return True
    #     else:
    #         return False
            
######  
    def packItemInOrder(self, bin, item, fix_point, check_stable, support_surface_ratio):
    # Logic to pack the item based on the order set in the Packer class
        for axis in range(0, 3):
            items_in_bin = bin.items
            for ib in items_in_bin:
                pivot = [0, 0, 0]
                w, h, d = ib.getDimension()
                if axis == Axis.WIDTH:
                    pivot = [ib.position[0] + w, ib.position[1], ib.position[2]]
                elif axis == Axis.HEIGHT:
                    pivot = [ib.position[0], ib.position[1] + h, ib.position[2]]
                elif axis == Axis.DEPTH:
                    pivot = [ib.position[0], ib.position[1], ib.position[2] + d]

                if bin.putItem(item, pivot, axis):
                    return

#######

    def sortBinding(self,bin):
        ''' sorted by binding '''
        b,front,back = [],[],[]
        for i in range(len(self.binding)):
            b.append([]) 
            for item in self.items:
                if item.name in self.binding[i]:
                    b[i].append(item)
                elif item.name not in self.binding:
                    if len(b[0]) == 0 and item not in front:
                        front.append(item)
                    elif item not in back and item not in front:
                        back.append(item)

        min_c = min([len(i) for i in b])
        
        sort_bind =[]
        for i in range(min_c):
            for j in range(len(b)):
                sort_bind.append(b[j][i])
        
        for i in b:
            for j in i:
                if j not in sort_bind:
                    self.unfit_items.append(j)

        self.items = front + sort_bind + back
        return


    def putOrder(self):
        '''Arrange the order of items '''
        r = []
        for i in self.bins:
            # open top container
            if i.put_type == 2:
                i.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.position[0], reverse=False)
                i.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.position[1], reverse=False)
                i.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.position[2], reverse=False)
            # general container
            elif i.put_type == 1:
                i.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.position[1], reverse=False)
                i.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.position[2], reverse=False)
                i.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.position[0], reverse=False)
            else :
                pass
        return


    def gravityCenter(self,bin):
        ''' 
        Deviation Of Cargo gravity distribution
        ''' 
        w = int(bin.width)
        h = int(bin.height)
        d = int(bin.depth)

        area1 = [set(range(0,w//2+1)),set(range(0,h//2+1)),0]
        area2 = [set(range(w//2+1,w+1)),set(range(0,h//2+1)),0]
        area3 = [set(range(0,w//2+1)),set(range(h//2+1,h+1)),0]
        area4 = [set(range(w//2+1,w+1)),set(range(h//2+1,h+1)),0]
        area = [area1,area2,area3,area4]

        for i in bin.items:

            x_st = int(i.position[0])
            y_st = int(i.position[1])
            if i.rotation_type == 0:
                x_ed = int(i.position[0] + i.width)
                y_ed = int(i.position[1] + i.height)
            elif i.rotation_type == 1:
                x_ed = int(i.position[0] + i.height)
                y_ed = int(i.position[1] + i.width)
            elif i.rotation_type == 2:
                x_ed = int(i.position[0] + i.height)
                y_ed = int(i.position[1] + i.depth)
            elif i.rotation_type == 3:
                x_ed = int(i.position[0] + i.depth)
                y_ed = int(i.position[1] + i.height)
            elif i.rotation_type == 4:
                x_ed = int(i.position[0] + i.depth)
                y_ed = int(i.position[1] + i.width)
            elif i.rotation_type == 5:
                x_ed = int(i.position[0] + i.width)
                y_ed = int(i.position[1] + i.depth)

            x_set = set(range(x_st,int(x_ed)+1))
            y_set = set(range(y_st,y_ed+1))

            # cal gravity distribution
            for j in range(len(area)):
                if x_set.issubset(area[j][0]) and y_set.issubset(area[j][1]) : 
                    area[j][2] += int(i.weight)
                    break
                # include x and !include y
                elif x_set.issubset(area[j][0]) == True and y_set.issubset(area[j][1]) == False and len(y_set & area[j][1]) != 0 : 
                    y = len(y_set & area[j][1]) / (y_ed - y_st) * int(i.weight)
                    area[j][2] += y
                    if j >= 2 :
                        area[j-2][2] += (int(i.weight) - x)
                    else :
                        area[j+2][2] += (int(i.weight) - y)
                    break
                # include y and !include x
                elif x_set.issubset(area[j][0]) == False and y_set.issubset(area[j][1]) == True and len(x_set & area[j][0]) != 0 : 
                    x = len(x_set & area[j][0]) / (x_ed - x_st) * int(i.weight)
                    area[j][2] += x
                    if j >= 2 :
                        area[j-2][2] += (int(i.weight) - x)
                    else :
                        area[j+2][2] += (int(i.weight) - x)
                    break
                # !include x and !include y
                elif x_set.issubset(area[j][0])== False and y_set.issubset(area[j][1]) == False and len(y_set & area[j][1]) != 0  and len(x_set & area[j][0]) != 0 :
                    all = (y_ed - y_st) * (x_ed - x_st)
                    y = len(y_set & area[0][1])
                    y_2 = y_ed - y_st - y
                    x = len(x_set & area[0][0])
                    x_2 = x_ed - x_st - x
                    area[0][2] += x * y / all * int(i.weight)
                    area[1][2] += x_2 * y / all * int(i.weight)
                    area[2][2] += x * y_2 / all * int(i.weight)
                    area[3][2] += x_2 * y_2 / all * int(i.weight)
                    break
            
        r = [area[0][2],area[1][2],area[2][2],area[3][2]]
        result = []
        for i in r :
            result.append(round(i / sum(r) * 100,2))
        return result


    def pack(self, bigger_first=False,distribute_items=True,fix_point=True,check_stable=True,support_surface_ratio=0.75,binding=[],number_of_decimals=DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_DECIMALS):
        '''pack master func '''
        # set decimals
        for bin in self.bins:
            bin.formatNumbers(number_of_decimals)

        for item in self.items:
            item.formatNumbers(number_of_decimals)
        # add binding attribute
        self.binding = binding
        # Bin : sorted by volumn
        self.bins.sort(key=lambda bin: bin.getVolume(), reverse=bigger_first)
        # Item : sorted by volumn -> sorted by loadbear -> sorted by level -> binding
        self.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.getVolume(), reverse=bigger_first)
        # self.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.getMaxArea(), reverse=bigger_first)
        self.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.loadbear, reverse=True)
        self.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.level, reverse=False)
        # sorted by binding
        if binding != []:
            self.sortBinding(bin)

        for idx,bin in enumerate(self.bins):
            # pack item to bin
            for item in self.items:
                self.pack2Bin(bin, item, fix_point, check_stable, support_surface_ratio)

            if binding != []:
                # resorted
                self.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.getVolume(), reverse=bigger_first)
                self.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.loadbear, reverse=True)
                self.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.level, reverse=False)
                # clear bin
                bin.items = []
                bin.unfitted_items = self.unfit_items
                bin.fit_items = np.array([[0,bin.width,0,bin.height,0,0]])
                # repacking
                for item in self.items:
                    self.pack2Bin(bin, item,fix_point,check_stable,support_surface_ratio)
            
            # Deviation Of Cargo Gravity Center 
            self.bins[idx].gravity = self.gravityCenter(bin)

            if distribute_items :
                for bitem in bin.items:
                    no = bitem.partno
                    for item in self.items :
                        if item.partno == no :
                            self.items.remove(item)
                            break

        # put order of items
        self.putOrder()

        if self.items != []:
            self.unfit_items = copy.deepcopy(self.items)
            self.items = []
        # for item in self.items.copy():
        #     if item in bin.unfitted_items:
        #         self.items.remove(item)
```

And here is the Bin Class:

```
class Bin:

    def __init__(self, partno, WHD, max_weight,corner=0,put_type=1):
        ''' '''
        self.partno = partno
        self.width = WHD[0]
        self.height = WHD[1]
        self.depth = WHD[2]
        self.max_weight = max_weight
        self.corner = corner
        self.items = []
        self.fit_items = np.array([[0,WHD[0],0,WHD[1],0,0]])
        self.unfitted_items = []
        self.number_of_decimals = DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_DECIMALS
        self.fix_point = False
        self.check_stable = False
        self.support_surface_ratio = 0
        self.put_type = put_type
        # used to put gravity distribution
        self.gravity = []


    def formatNumbers(self, number_of_decimals):
        ''' '''
        self.width = set2Decimal(self.width, number_of_decimals)
        self.height = set2Decimal(self.height, number_of_decimals)
        self.depth = set2Decimal(self.depth, number_of_decimals)
        self.max_weight = set2Decimal(self.max_weight, number_of_decimals)
        self.number_of_decimals = number_of_decimals


    def string(self):
        ''' '''
        return "%s(%sx%sx%s, max_weight:%s) vol(%s)" % (
            self.partno, self.width, self.height, self.depth, self.max_weight,
            self.getVolume()
        )


    def getVolume(self):
        ''' '''
        return set2Decimal(
            self.width * self.height * self.depth, self.number_of_decimals
        )


    def getTotalWeight(self):
        ''' '''
        total_weight = 0

        for item in self.items:
            total_weight += item.weight

        return set2Decimal(total_weight, self.number_of_decimals)


    def putItem(self, item, pivot,axis=None):
        ''' put item in bin '''
#####


####
        fit = False
        valid_item_position = item.position
        item.position = pivot
        
        rotate = RotationType.ALL if item.updown == True else RotationType.Notupdown
        for i in range(0, len(rotate)):
            item.rotation_type = i
            dimension = item.getDimension()
            # rotatate

            ######
            #  # Ensure the item does not exceed the bin boundaries
            # if (
            #     pivot[0] + dimension[0] > self.width or
            #     pivot[1] + dimension[1] > self.height or
            #     pivot[2] + dimension[2] > self.depth
            # ):
            #     continue

            # fit = True

            # # Check if the item intersects with the walking room boundaries
            # walking_room_x = self.width / 4
            # walking_room_y = self.height / 2
            # walking_room_z = self.depth

            # if (
            #     pivot[0] < walking_room_x or pivot[0] + dimension[0] > walking_room_x + 24 or
            #     pivot[1] < walking_room_y or pivot[1] + dimension[1] > walking_room_y + 24 or
            #     pivot[2] + dimension[2] > walking_room_z
            # ):
            #     fit = False
            #     break

            ##### 
             
            if (
                self.width < pivot[0] + dimension[0] or
                self.height < pivot[1] + dimension[1] or
                self.depth < pivot[2] + dimension[2]
            ):
                continue

            fit = True

            for current_item_in_bin in self.items:
                if intersect(current_item_in_bin, item):
                    fit = False
                    break

            if fit:
                # cal total weight
                if self.getTotalWeight() + item.weight > self.max_weight:
                    print("Too Heavy for container: ", self.item.partno)
                    fit = False
                    return fit
                
                # fix point float prob
                if self.fix_point == True :
                        
                    [w,h,d] = dimension
                    [x,y,z] = [float(pivot[0]),float(pivot[1]),float(pivot[2])]

                    for i in range(3):
                        # fix height
                        y = self.checkHeight([x,x+float(w),y,y+float(h),z,z+float(d)])
                        # fix width
                        x = self.checkWidth([x,x+float(w),y,y+float(h),z,z+float(d)])
                        # fix depth
                        z = self.checkDepth([x,x+float(w),y,y+float(h),z,z+float(d)])

                    # check stability on item 
                    # rule : 
                    # 1. Define a support ratio, if the ratio below the support surface does not exceed this ratio, compare the second rule.
                    # 2. If there is no support under any vertices of the bottom of the item, then fit = False.
                    if self.check_stable == True :
                        # Cal the surface area of ​​item.
                        # item_area_lower = int(dimension[0] * dimension[1])
                        item_area_lower = dimension[0] * dimension[1]
                        # Cal the surface area of ​​the underlying support.
                        support_area_upper = 0
                        for i in self.fit_items:
                            # Verify that the lower support surface area is greater than the upper support surface area * support_surface_ratio.
                            if z == i[5]  :
                                area = len(set([ j for j in range(int(x),int(x+int(w)))]) & set([ j for j in range(int(i[0]),int(i[1]))])) * \
                                len(set([ j for j in range(int(y),int(y+int(h)))]) & set([ j for j in range(int(i[2]),int(i[3]))]))
                                support_area_upper += area

                        # If not , get four vertices of the bottom of the item.
                        if support_area_upper / item_area_lower < self.support_surface_ratio :
                            four_vertices = [[x,y],[x+float(w),y],[x,y+float(h)],[x+float(w),y+float(h)]]
                            #  If any vertices is not supported, fit = False.
                            c = [False,False,False,False]
                            for i in self.fit_items:
                                if z == i[5] :
                                    for jdx,j in enumerate(four_vertices) :
                                        if (i[0] <= j[0] <= i[1]) and (i[2] <= j[1] <= i[3]) :
                                            c[jdx] = True
                            if False in c :
                                item.position = valid_item_position
                                fit = False
                                return fit
                        
                    self.fit_items = np.append(self.fit_items,np.array([[x,x+float(w),y,y+float(h),z,z+float(d)]]),axis=0)
                    item.position = [set2Decimal(x),set2Decimal(y),set2Decimal(z)]

                if fit :
                    self.items.append(copy.deepcopy(item))
# indented line
            else :
                item.position = valid_item_position

            return fit

        else :
            item.position = valid_item_position

        return fit


    def checkDepth(self,unfix_point):
        ''' fix item position z '''
        z_ = [[0,0],[float(self.depth),float(self.depth)]]
        for j in self.fit_items:
            # creat x set
            x_bottom = set([i for i in range(int(j[0]),int(j[1]))])
            x_top = set([i for i in range(int(unfix_point[0]),int(unfix_point[1]))])
            # creat y set
            y_bottom = set([i for i in range(int(j[2]),int(j[3]))])
            y_top = set([i for i in range(int(unfix_point[2]),int(unfix_point[3]))])
            # find intersection on x set and y set.
            if len(x_bottom & x_top) != 0 and len(y_bottom & y_top) != 0 :
                z_.append([float(j[4]),float(j[5])])
        top_depth = unfix_point[5] - unfix_point[4]
        # find diff set on z_.
        z_ = sorted(z_, key = lambda z_ : z_[1])
        for j in range(len(z_)-1):
            if z_[j+1][0] -z_[j][1] >= top_depth:
                return z_[j][1]
        return unfix_point[4]


    def checkWidth(self,unfix_point):
        ''' fix item position x ''' 
        x_ = [[0,0],[float(self.width),float(self.width)]]
        for j in self.fit_items:
            # creat z set
            z_bottom = set([i for i in range(int(j[4]),int(j[5]))])
            z_top = set([i for i in range(int(unfix_point[4]),int(unfix_point[5]))])
            # creat y set
            y_bottom = set([i for i in range(int(j[2]),int(j[3]))])
            y_top = set([i for i in range(int(unfix_point[2]),int(unfix_point[3]))])
            # find intersection on z set and y set.
            if len(z_bottom & z_top) != 0 and len(y_bottom & y_top) != 0 :
                x_.append([float(j[0]),float(j[1])])
        top_width = unfix_point[1] - unfix_point[0]
        # find diff set on x_bottom and x_top.
        x_ = sorted(x_,key = lambda x_ : x_[1])
        for j in range(len(x_)-1):
            if x_[j+1][0] -x_[j][1] >= top_width:
                return x_[j][1]
        return unfix_point[0]
    

    def checkHeight(self,unfix_point):
        '''fix item position y '''
        y_ = [[0,0],[float(self.height),float(self.height)]]
        for j in self.fit_items:
            # creat x set
            x_bottom = set([i for i in range(int(j[0]),int(j[1]))])
            x_top = set([i for i in range(int(unfix_point[0]),int(unfix_point[1]))])
            # creat z set
            z_bottom = set([i for i in range(int(j[4]),int(j[5]))])
            z_top = set([i for i in range(int(unfix_point[4]),int(unfix_point[5]))])
            # find intersection on x set and z set.
            if len(x_bottom & x_top) != 0 and len(z_bottom & z_top) != 0 :
                y_.append([float(j[2]),float(j[3])])
        top_height = unfix_point[3] - unfix_point[2]
        # find diff set on y_bottom and y_top.
        y_ = sorted(y_,key = lambda y_ : y_[1])
        for j in range(len(y_)-1):
            if y_[j+1][0] -y_[j][1] >= top_height:
                return y_[j][1]

        return unfix_point[2]


    def addCorner(self):
        '''add container coner '''
        if self.corner != 0 :
            corner = set2Decimal(self.corner)
            corner_list = []
            for i in range(8):
                a = Item(
                    partno='corner{}'.format(i),
                    name='corner', 
                    typeof='cube',
                    WHD=(corner,corner,corner), 
                    weight=0, 
                    level=0, 
                    loadbear=0, 
                    updown=True, 
                    color='#000000'
                    # color='#fa0202'
                    )

                corner_list.append(a)
            return corner_list


    def putCorner(self,info,item):
        '''put coner in bin '''
        fit = False
        x = set2Decimal(self.width - self.corner)
        y = set2Decimal(self.height - self.corner)
        z = set2Decimal(self.depth - self.corner)
        pos = [[0,0,0],[0,0,z],[0,y,z],[0,y,0],[x,y,0],[x,0,0],[x,0,z],[x,y,z]]
        item.position = pos[info]
        self.items.append(item)

        corner = [float(item.position[0]),float(item.position[0])+float(self.corner),float(item.position[1]),float(item.position[1])+float(self.corner),float(item.position[2]),float(item.position[2])+float(self.corner)]

        self.fit_items = np.append(self.fit_items,np.array([corner]),axis=0)
        return


    def clearBin(self):
        ''' clear item which in bin '''
        self.items = []
        self.fit_items = np.array([[0,self.width,0,self.height,0,0]])
        return
```

I have commented out the areas I generally work in to try to get the dimensions lined up. This script has become quite large so not sure if I need to add the entire thing but any ideas or related issues would help out a lot.

In my mind, Logic should be get bin/container size, determine if and where the walking room dimensions will be, adjust how to pack items in the order the Packer has set and remove the items that will not fit bin, plot items in the Painter (a class using matplotlib-3d) and add to Gui

Comment: As far as the question of which class the walking room option should go in, I think the options are set the area of usable bin space in the bin class and then pack normally with the allowed space or add the walking room in the packer class and say when packing avoid this area.  Maybe?